# Passing compiled expressions to where() clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using calculated properties on my EF object which can't be passed directly to a `where()` clause:

`{"The specified type member 'SomeProp' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."}`

Based on what I read on SO, this could be avoided by passing a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as the argument to `where()`.

Compiling the expression to a `Func` works fine:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = e => f => f.SomeCalculatedProperty == 1;
Func<Foo, bool> compiled = expr.Compile();
Foo result = dbContext.Foo.Where(compiled);
```

But passing the expression gives me the error above, i.e:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> expr = e => f => f.SomeCalculatedProperty == 1;
Foo result = dbContext.Foo.Where(e);
```

Based on [this](http://www.atrevido.net/blog/2007/09/05/Calling+Custom+Methods+In+LINQtoSQL.aspx), shouldn't the last example work fine?

Comment: Your first and third snippets are functionally identical.  There must be some difference that you haven't shown for one to work and another to not.

Comment: You can never get EF to query against calculated properties whatever you do because they are not in the database so your expresion can't be turned into SQL so you will have to query them in memory. If you want to do that just call `AsEnumerable()` before any expressions that reference the calculated properties.

Comment: This can help: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/07/projecting-computed-properties-with-linq-and-automapper/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In example one you are calling the extension method [`Queryable.Where<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535040(v=vs.100).aspx) this converts the query to sql and applies the filter server side.

In example two you are calling the extension method [`Enumerable.Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx), this returns all rows from the database then in memory in the program it applies the filter.

For your third example, I will just quote [Servy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976321/passing-compiled-expressions-to-where-clause#comment42487436_26976321)

> Your first and third snippets are functionally identical. There must
>   be some difference that you haven't shown for one to work and another
>   to not.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My "real" codes actually chains to where clauses e.g. `dbContext.Foo.Where(x => x == 1).Where(func)` / `dbContext.Foo.Where(x => x == 1).Where(f => f.SomeCalculatedProperty == 1)`. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @Johan Having a second `Where` wouldn't have any effect on this behavior, nor does it change the fact that, as shown, both code snippets are functionally identical.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, looks like I was a bit too quick on my simplified example. I will update the question.